# listen to the Internet Explorer download event

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I need to write an application in C# and VS2010 that can listen to the download event from Internet Explorer and capture the file URL to add it to a certain database.

My only problem is on how to implement an interface that actually captures that event.

What would I need in order to build or implement such functionality?

Looking for functionality as the "Free download manager or FDM software", each time you start a download on Internet Explorer, a "FDM" window pops up containing the URL of the download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a **browser helper object**. These are COM components so you can develop them using C# but you need to expose them to COM.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx) is a primer to the COM programming in C#.

## UPDATE

It seems <s>the only way</s> it is possible to write browser helper object in C++. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Helper_Object#Examples_of_BHO has a link to C# examples - I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks mark, so what I said first was indeed correct. I will update.

Comment: Thanky very much Mark, the link you provided taked me to the following example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Attach_BHO_with_C_.aspx and it works like a charm, now it's only matter of figuring out how to link the event to my application and send the URL to be downloaded.

Comment: The answer still doesn't answer to the question how with BHO's, that's a very general answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
    public class BHO:IObjectWithSite
    {
        private WebBrowser webBrowser;

        public int SetSite(object site){
                webBrowser = (WebBrowser)site;
                webBrowser.DownloadComplete +=new DWebBrowserEvents2_DownloadCompleteEventHandler(webBrowser_DownloadComplete);
       (...)
   }
```